# Microservices template project for Play Framework with java

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.5

I want to create a multi project helloWorld for microservices in Play 2.5 using java and I cannot find any appropiate template or tutorial to start.
My problem is that I want to create a to projects that can be run at the same time and can be both accessible through REST interface.

Any idea?

Comment: https://www.lightbend.com/activator/template/playing-microservices
Its on 2.4 but i guess you can have an idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey It's all about sbt multi project configuration example:

```
name := "microservices"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.8"

autoScalaLibrary := false


def module(id: String, names: String) = Project(id, file(names))
  .settings(javacOptions in compile ++= Seq("-encoding", "UTF-8", "-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint:unchecked", "-Xlint:deprecation"))
  .settings(jacksonParameterNamesJavacSettings: _*)

lazy val jacksonParameterNamesJavacSettings = Seq(
  javacOptions in compile += "-parameters"
)

lazy val common = module("common", "modules/common")
lazy val aws = module("aws", "modules/aws")
  .aggregate(common)
  .dependsOn(common)

lazy val keywords = module("keywords", "keywords")
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
  .dependsOn(common, aws)
  .aggregate(common, aws)

lazy val users = module("users", "users")
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
  .dependsOn(common, aws)
  .aggregate(common, aws)
```

example of folder structure:

- root:

  - users

    - project
  - keywords

    - project
  - modules:

    - common
    - aws

users/build.sbt

```
name := """users"""
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.8"
PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("play.server.http.port" -> "9001")
// application version release
version := "2.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.4"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

dockerExposedPorts in Docker := Seq(9001)
```

keywords/build.sbt

```
name := """keywords"""

PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("play.server.http.port" -> "9002")
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.8"
// application version release
version := "1.0"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.12",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "6.0.4"
)

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator

dockerExposedPorts in Docker := Seq(9000)
```

Then you need to run sbt and navigate to desired project and run it so you run them as two separated processes:

- 1 process:

  - sbt; project users; run;
  - this will run on 9001
- 2 process:

  - sbt; project keywords; run;
  - this will run on 9002

I will provide you example template on github tomorrow.